# Hecke eigenvalues of Siegel Modular forms of level greater than two

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

I wish to compute Hecke eigenvalues of Siegel Modular forms of level greater than two using the software like SAGE OR MAGMA. Is it possible to do the same?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to either system; but probably there are people who have written code of their own for this. Have you tried asking Alex Ghitza?